# How can I boot to DOS with a UEFI BIOS? (re: updating BIOS)

Tags: bios, updates, uefi

I have a Supermicro X9SCM-F motherboard and I'd like to upgrade the BIOS because I'm having trouble installing Windows 8.1 (and apparently I'm on a very old BIOS).

However, I can't seem to boot to DOS using USB sticks because the BIOS is only UEFI and I can't find a UEFI DOS boot image.

Comment: It seems unlikely that a UEFI motherboard, especially one that lacks a BIOS compatibility module, would require DOS for doing firmware updates.  There's a good chance that you can just put the update file on a flash drive and do the upgrade from within the UEFI environment itself.

Comment: @Wyzard I think it's a pretty big assumption to say that there is no CSM. Perhaps he has "legacy boot" disabled in his setup.